# matlab: Is a field of structure array actually a named cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell

I've googled topics about difference between cell array and array and had a vision that cell array actually stores pointers to content of elements.

Operator `{}` is like `&` in C, right?

When `{}` is applied to a variable `{var_a,var_b}`, we get a 1*2 "cell pointers" array to `var_a` and `var_b`? Is there a name for the "cell pointer"?

Does structure array take similar memory arrangement?

Take the example in the matlab document:

```
patient.name = 'John Doe';
patient.billing = 127.00;
patient.test = [79, 75, 73; 180, 178, 177.5; 172, 170, 169];

patient(2).name = 'Ann Lane';
patient(2).billing = 28.50;
patient(2).test = [68, 70, 68; 118, 118, 119; 172, 170, 169];
```

so the variable patient is like a 2*3 cell array except the field name?

```
patientcell{2,3}=...
```

I was wondering the notion below:

The dot operator in structure makes a deference to its content:

```
patient(1).test;
```

=> 
    patientcell{1,3}

right?

Comment: For more insight, I'd recommend digging into the MEX API to get a feel for [how the underlying `mxArray` works](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/access-data.html) behind the scenes - even numeric arrays really only store pointers to their data (it's how the copy-on-write mechanism works, for one thing)

Comment: I think that to accomplish copy-on-write, numeric arrays just store pointer to the starting element, which is different from cell array. The link in your post is an api list, without detail implementation. It's a pity that mathworks hide these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Preallocation of cell array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855275/preallocation-of-cell-array-in-matlab)

> It is reasonable to assume that a cell array is implemented as a
>   continuous array of pointers, each pointing to the actual content of
>   the cell.

[How do i define a structure in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166438/how-do-i-define-a-structure-in-matlab)

> the structure is simply an array of pointer[s]

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hesitation that structure contains pointers two. Maybe it's a ambiguous itself about the analogy of 2-dimension cell array to structure array. After all, we don't the implementation beneath, and Mathworks don't take this semantic equivalence about the two.